# How to make this code work on PHP 5.3.3

Tags: php

I am developing on a server that only supports PHP 5.3.3. I am trying to use Elasticsearch, but it gives me this error: `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[' in C:\wamp\www\test3\es.php on line 6` The code works perfectly on PHP 5.6+ Here's the code:

```
<?php
    require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';
    use Elasticsearch\ClientBuilder;

    /*Build connection*/
    $hosts = [   //<<<<---- Line 6
    'xx.x.xxx.xxx',                // IP + Port
];

    $es = ClientBuilder::create()    // Instantiate a new ClientBuilder
            ->setHosts($hosts)      // Set the hosts
            ->build();             // Build the client object

?>
```

It is not recognizing the bracket where it says `$hosts = [` Is there a way I can make this code run on PHP 5.3.3?

Comment: Use `array()` not `[]`.

Comment: Simplified array declarations were added to [PHP 5.4](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/migration54.new-features.php).